# Why my swift 3,acer is not booting?

Tags: boot, laptop, window, laptop-display, acer

Swift 3, 512SSD and 8 Gb RAM is not booting, first I was in sleeping mode so I boot the laptop it seem it has some problems mouse is not working so I restart it and then after it is not responding, it is only showing the Acer logo and below loading icon, I already tried 2,3 time power on and off using power button, laptop is in good just bought 1 year ago I generally takes 2,3 second to boot but now it is more than a hour it is not responding what should I do to solve this?

Comment: (1) Do you get any beeps when booting? (2) Do you hear the fans when powering on? (3) Is the computer under warranty?

Comment: As @harrymc states, take it back on warranty, if feasible. If not, try booting from USB, e.g., live Ubuntu, salvage data, then try to fix Windows, perhaps reinstalling, saving files.

Comment: @harrymc 1) No there isn't any beeps 2) yes fans are working as usual no any loud sound  3) unfortunately warranty just expire 2 months ago

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible directions now :

- Start buying and replacing parts
- Bring the computer to a repair-shop and pay just for the bad part
  and the work.

In most such cases, the second method is more cost-effective.

Comment: This depends on where you live, in the EU you have the right to cancel and return your order within 14 days, for any reason and without a justification. So I just bought a bunch of parts, kept the part that fixed the problem, and returned everything else.

Comment: I should specify that this law applies to online purchases.  And don't do this to mom-and-pop shops! If you live in the EU and have a problem that is hard to diagnose this is a great way to simplify your life.